# Background image does not render in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a single webpage.

```
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<title> Welcome to domain.com!</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

And a css file

```
body {
    background-image: url("../pics/city7.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    display: inline-block;  }
```

It works perfectly (scaling) in chrome. But in firefox it is just a bunch of lines. I tried using display: inline-block - but that does not fix the problem. I am not even sure what it is doing. From what I know (and it aint much at this point) is that if I put the image in HTML it will override the CSS - can someone points me in the right direction?

Comment: could you please attach some screenshots?

Comment: screen shot is to large. I did just notice that if I right click in Firefox and select View Background image - I can see the image fine in the browser.

Comment: you can link them from imgur or sth

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BysNK3swBWm2QksxSEFFNlVIUGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: try changing 100% to 99.99% - some time ago there were a bug in mozilla when background scaling - maybe it is the reason - what is the Mozilla version you observe bug on? or maybe any version?

Comment: using 40.0.3 testing on linux and windows 7 - same results on both machines. Tried changing to 99% but same problem.

Comment: When I goto Tools, Page Info Media (in firefox) is do see the image in Media Preview - even though it does not load in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS file, you could write something like:

```
html {
  min-height: 100%;

}

body {
  background-image: url("../pics/city7.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: That works - can you tell me if this would effect content when I develop it on top of the image?